# Question about proof of subsets

Tags: trigonometry, proof-explanation

So, I came across this question:
Prove or disprove that A = {x ∈ R | sin(x) > cos(x)} is a subset of B = {y ∈ R | sin²(y) > cos²(y)}.

And I decided to solve this via turning the equations in the conditions into equations that contained tangent. That is, the sets became:
A = {x ∈ R | tan(x) > 1}
B = {y ∈ R | tan²(y) > 1}.

And I concluded that, within the domain [0, π], A = (π/4, π/2), and B = (π/4, 3π/4) \ {π/2}, and hence the set A was indeed a subset of B, with the use of a graphing calculator.

However, this answer was wrong. In reality, set A is not a subset of B. When you find all x in {x ∈ R | sin(x) > cos(x)} and all y in {y ∈ R | sin²(y) > cos²(y)} by NOT converting the conditional equations into tangents and just leaving them how they are, you can see that A = (π/4, 5π/4) and B = (π/4, 3π/4) U (5π/4, 7π/4). So, why the disparity? I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is not subset of $B$.

$x=\pi\in A$

$\sin(\pi)=0  > -1=\cos(\pi) $

But $\pi\notin B$

$\sin^2(\pi) =0 <\cos^2(\pi) =1$

Comment: I get that, but my question is why does manipulating the conditional equations cause you to get different set intervals for A and B and hence cause you to get the answer wrong?